# TinyMCE does not apply font-size and text-color while project is on the web

Tags: javascript, tinymce, font-size, textcolor

I've used TinyMCE in my projects. It works well when I run the web application locally. But when I put the files on the internet, text-color and font-size don't apply in the formatting.
What's the problem ?

Comment: have you checked that your css file is actually being loaded by the browser?

Comment: @AidanEwen as I mentioned, it works without any problem when I run it locally

Comment: Identify the css file that sets the styles. Then look in your browsers debugging tools to see if it's actually being loaded when you run it remotely. You need to use something like Chrome's Network panel overview to make this check - https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#network_panel_overview

Comment: I checked it @AidanEwen. It loads needed files.

Comment: you should show your usecase - ideally in jsfiddle example

Comment: @Tomas, please look at http://jsfiddle.net/XuG8N/. Unfortunatelly as it needs loading images too, the appearance is not visible in jsfiddle. But codes are what I have used in my project

Comment: I have never experienced this issue. I have created a [TinyMCE Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/RMdaab) for you to play with. Only disabled the language setting. It is working for me from here. Select your tinymce version and tell us if it works for you here. This will more-or-less filter if it is a specific version issue or browser issue.

Comment: what about security on the Javascript files?

Comment: @SoonDead, version is 4.0.12. I tested it, and it worked without problem. I don't know what is the cause of my problem :(

Comment: Did you change any files on the web server directory short ago? Then please set the caching time from your webserver to a smaller timespan, to avoid getting an older version of files from the web server cache instead of the newer one, which is already stored on hard disc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the problem when I saw the source of page.
This is what is stored in databae for one of that items:

```
<span style=\"font-size: 24pt; color: #ff0000;\">
```

When I removed `\` from stored data, problem got solved. I'm using PDO to connect PHP with MySQL. So I think it is escaping double quotes.
So the solution is about preventing PDO to escape double quotes.

Thank you all to getting participate in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got an another rule that overrides your font style.

The fact that the development and production version diverge is a little weird, have you try to clean your cache (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) ?
Like @Aiden Ewen said, you should view the rule being applied to an element by inspect it using the developers tools, and easily target the file and line where is located this rule.

[image: Inspector]

Here you can see the color black is applied to `#question-header a` in the `all.css` file.

You can also try, if it is not already, to add the keyword `important` next to the CSS rules you want to apply at the TinyMCE.